# Genesis 19:26 - Was Lot's wife really behind Lot?

Tags: genesis

> 26 But Lot’s wife looked back, and she became a pillar of salt. (NIV)

> 26 But his wife looked back **from behind him**, and she became a pillar of salt. (KJV)

> 26 But Lot’s wife, **from behind him**, looked back, and she became a pillar of salt. (NASB)

The phrase "from behind him" create a problem. For Lot's wife looked back and became a pillar of salt. If she was behind Lot, Lot had to looked back to see his wife became a pillar of salt, then why Lot did not become a pillar of salt?

Did NIV intentionally remove the phrase to avoid this perplexity?

Comment: Did the one who downvote has an answer to share?

Comment: @Dottard, H310 ('aḥar) is translated as "from behind him".  Should it really be "to behind her" even though it has a masculine suffix?

Comment: @Dottard Hebrew grammar is not the same as English.  Hebrew certainly has the "behind" there, and the "from" is not necessary in this case in Hebrew (and not there) but it is necessary in English.  One does not say in English: "she became pillar salt"--yet that's what the Hebrew says if one takes a very literal reading (without understanding Hebrew construct chains).  We add prepositions and articles that English grammar requires.  The same is true here.  Hebrew readers will understand that Lot's wife was behind him when she looked back.  How would you prefer to translate that?

Comment: @Biblasia - "she looked behind" or "she looked back"?

Comment: @Dottard The word "back" and/or "behind" occurs only once in the Hebrew for this verse.  It has the third-person masculine singular pronominal suffix.  Because it is talking about Lot's _wife_, a woman, we know that the masculine pronoun refers to Lot, her husband.  So if you want to translate that as "back of him" or "behind him", either one will serve.  For comparison, another text that uses the exact same Hebrew word is 2 Samuel 11:15 where the soldiers were commanded to put Uriah in the front, then turn back from behind him (translated various ways, depending on Bible version).

Comment: @Biblasia - yours explanation is helpful to me who don't know Hebrew. Thank you!

Comment: @VincentWong Having completed three 30-week courses in Hebrew, I still feel I know very little of it. Hebrew is a very complex language, and just to know how to pronounce the words can take months or years of study. But with the little bit I have learned I am better able to understand the online study tools for it. I know more Chinese than Hebrew, but would say Hebrew is far more difficult. Chinese grammar is extremely simple by comparison. Did you know that there are a possible 490 verb forms (not tenses) for a Hebrew verb? (Any given verb will not be used with all the forms, though).

Comment: @Biblasia - I would say you have a talent in languages

Answer (score 2):

Lot was instructed not to look behind him while fleeing to the little town of Zoar. That town was to be spared destruction, at Lot's request, seeing as the initial instruction to flee to the mountains was too great a distance for him. The instruction was that destruction could not start until he had "come thither" to Zoar. When Lot entered Zoar, the sun had risen and then brimstone and fire was rained down upon Sodom and Gomorrah. See Genesis 19:17-26.

The next bit of information in the account is that Lot's wife must have been behind Lot when she decided to turn around and look back. The account does not say exactly when she disobeyed, but it could have been just as Lot and the two daughters were about to enter Zoar. They hastened in, but if the wife turned around, being behind and hearing the noise of the awful events hurtling down from heaven, and stopped to then gaze at the fire and brimstone falling at that point, she would have been included in the conflagration's extreme reaches.

Zoar was to be spared, but only those inside it would likewise be spared. If the noise marking the commencement of the fire from heaven caught her attention just before she got to Zoar, and she turned then, not moving as the catastrophe started to be seen by her, that could explain why Lot did not  turn in disobedience himself.  He probably didn't notice his wife was not with the daughters until the three were safely in Zoar, then looked to see her standing outside, and lo! She was a pillar of salt!

So, **yes, Lot's wife really would have been behind Lot.** By the time he saw what had happened to her, he and the daughters would have been safely inside Zoar. The indication is that the wife was outside that town. ***The phrase "from behind him" does not create any problem.*** You would have to ask the NIV translators why they did not include the phrase.

Comment: Yours is one possible scenario. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently no variance in the underlying Hebrew manuscripts for Genesis 19:26, so the difference in English is just a matter of translation.  The NIV translators may well have removed that phrase because they felt it was unnecessary, but they may also have simply understood it differently, thinking that the Hebrew word spoke of where Lot's wife was *looking* instead of where she was *standing* at the time of looking.  (The word "behind" or "back" or "backward" only occurs once in the Hebrew text.)

Translators for the other Bible versions are reading the Hebrew to say that Lot's wife was behind him when she looked, and the "looked back" is just stating the obvious as to which direction she was looking.

Keep in mind that Lot did not write this account.  It was written by Moses, many years after the fact, under inspiration.  It was not necessary for someone to be physically present to know what happened when God chose to reveal it.  But there is another important point here:  When Mrs. Lot was turned into salt, others who passed by later would clearly see where she had been looking at that moment.  God left her there for the purpose of instructing others of future generations.

Comment: you get a point that it was written by Moses